# Finding a drive adapter to re-use the old hard drive from a Macbook Pro early 2015 13"

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, usb, hardware, ssd

I recently upgraded the hard-drive on my Macbook Pro 13" early 2015 model. I'd like to use the old 128gb hard-drive as an external USB disk, but I'm having trouble finding the adapter to make it a USB drive. This MacBook Pro uses a proprietary storage drive connector.

So far I've bought the wrong adapter (for M.2 drives to fit the Macbook, which is the wrong direction.)

[image]

The model number of the old hard-drive is MZ-JPV1280/03 (Samsung).

I have this NGFF-to-USB3 box standing by:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite possible that there may not **be** an adaptor. I don't believe Apple used these for very long, so...

I would think returning it and getting one of the OWC drive adapters for that specific drive would do the trick. Like this

[eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MAU3ENPRPCI](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MAU3ENPRPCI)

And to destroy an old SSD? Take a hammer to the individual chips on the drive's circuit board, that should do it. Try and recover data from plastic and silicon shards...